# image not updated when refreshed

Tags: java, android

new learner here. so i just started exploring android. more specifically on image. and now im trying the picasso library. my problem is when im using picasso, the new image that i uploaded to database is not updated on the imageView(2.PreviewImage.java). do help and tqvm in advanced. fyi. theres no issue when uploading image to database.

1.MainActivity.java

```
EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendSp);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void saveSpEmail(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PassingEmail", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("passEmail", editText.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreviewImage.class);
    //intent.putExtra("email", editText.getText().toString());
    saveSpEmail();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

2.PreviewImage.java

```
Button buttonCoProfileUploadClinicImage;

TextView textView;

private ImageView imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage;
private Bitmap bitmap;
String imagePath;

String receiveSpEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview_image);

    buttonCoProfileUploadClinicImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCoProfileUploadImage);
    buttonCoProfileUploadClinicImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);

    receiveSpEmail();
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //receiveSpEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email");
    textView.setText(receiveSpEmail);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCoProfileClinicImage);
    getCoImageProfile();

}

public void receiveSpEmail(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PassingEmail", MODE_PRIVATE);
    receiveSpEmail = preferences.getString("passEmail", "..");
}

//added for retrieve image - 13/2/16
private void getCoImageProfile() {

    String url = ClinicOwnerGetImage.DATA_URL+receiveSpEmail.toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showImageJSON(response);
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(imagePath);
            //imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Picasso.with(PreviewImage.this)
                    .load(imagePath)
                    //.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
                    // .error(R.drawable.error)      // optional
                    .resize(400, 400)                        // optional
                    .into(imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(PreviewImage.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void showImageJSON(String response){
    String image="";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ClinicOwnerGetImage.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject employeeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        image = employeeData.getString(ClinicOwnerGetImage.KEY_CLINIC_IMAGE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imagePath = image;
    Toast.makeText(this, imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
//end of retrieve image


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent CoUploadImage = new Intent(this, ClinicOwnerUploadImage.class);
    startActivity(CoUploadImage);
}
```

3.UploadImage.java

```
public class ClinicOwnerUploadImage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonCoChooseImage, buttonCoUploadImage;

private ImageView imageViewCoProfileImage;

public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "clinicimage";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://";
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Bitmap bitmap;
String receiveSpEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clinic_owner_upload_image);

    buttonCoChooseImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCoChooseImage);
    buttonCoChooseImage.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonCoUploadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCoUploadImage);
    buttonCoUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);

    imageViewCoProfileImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCoUploadImage);

    receiveSpEmail();

}

public void receiveSpEmail(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PassingEmail", MODE_PRIVATE);
    receiveSpEmail = preferences.getString("passEmail", "..");
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(filePath)
                            //.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
                            // .error(R.drawable.error)      // optional
                    .resize(400, 400)                        // optional
                    .into(imageViewCoProfileImage);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

public void uploadImage(){
    final String email = receiveSpEmail.toString().trim();
    final String clinicimage = getStringImage(bitmap);
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ClinicOwnerUploadImage.this,"Please wait...","uploading",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ClinicOwnerUploadImage.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            CoUploadImageRequestHandler rh = new CoUploadImageRequestHandler();
            HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
            param.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
            param.put(KEY_IMAGE,clinicimage);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
            return result;
        }
    }
    UploadImage u = new UploadImage();
    u.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnCoChooseImage:
            showFileChooser();
            break;

        case R.id.btnCoUploadImage:
            uploadImage();
            Intent CoProfilePage = new Intent(this, PreviewImage.class);
            startActivity(CoProfilePage);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: u can also try universal library while both of it failed to load image from Google Drive in my case

Comment: when i use this line, imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap). it works. im guessing because bitmap is refreshed from getBitmapFromUrl. but picasso cannot use bitmap can it? picasso can only .load image from url right?

Comment: yes, picaso is for hassle-free image loading and provide you several advance feature to manipulae with it, but it failed to load image from Google Drive URI and loaded sucessfully with an URL pointing to image

Answer (score 0):

In `PreviewImage.java` inside `onResponse` method replace

```
Picasso.with(PreviewImage.this)
  .load(imagePath)
  //.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
  //.error(R.drawable.error)      // optional
  .resize(400, 400)                        // optional
  .into(imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage);
```

with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
                   Picasso.with(PreviewImage.this)
                  .load(imagePath)
                 //.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
                 //.error(R.drawable.error)      // optional
                  .resize(400, 400)                        // optional
                  .into(imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage);
           }
       });
```

Mention errors in question . Post your error log.

Comment: tq for helping but unfortunately it didnt work. actually theres no error produced. when i use picasso, it didnt load the right image and preview it to imageView. but when i use this line, imageViewCoProfilePageClinicImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap). it works. the bitmap is refreshed using getBitmapFromUrl but when using picasso, the imagePath is not updated with the latest image.